# Django/CSS static files not loading

Tags: javascript, css, django

I am using a template to make a customized website. However some static files are loading and some are not.

I get a red underline in my text editor in these locations:
[image]

[image]

```
<section class="dento-service-area section-padding-100-0 bg-img bg-gradient-overlay jarallax clearfix" style="background-image: url({% static 'website/img/bg-img/13.jpg' %});">
    <div class="container">
```

[image]

Any help in CSS formatting is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the code `{% load static %}` at the beginning of the document as it follows:

```
{% load static %}
<section 
  class="dento-service-area section-padding-100-0 bg-img bg-gradient-overlay 
  jarallax clearfix" 
  style="background-image: url({% static 'website/img/bg-img/13.jpg' %});"
>
    <div class="container">
```

Comment: Thank you, but I already have load static at top of document.

Comment: Does an error message appear? Can you insert a code from where it's not causing a problem?

Comment: The code in the first image above has this error ----> ) expectedcss(css-rparentexpected)

Comment: This error is due to spaces, try the code on a single line:
<div class="welcome-welcome-slide bg-img bg-gradient-overlay jarallax" style="background-image: url({% static 'website/img/bg-img/1.jpg' %});">
The meaning of css-rparentexpected is "Right parenthesis expected".

Comment: Thank you Matheus, it seems to be working now, even though the error is still showing, strange.

Answer (score 0):

first off most programs like vscode dont understand django template
so the redline is mostly not a problem

***first just add "" around the url()***
so like this url("{% static 'blahblah' %}")

***however if the django template is getting confused and when you go into dev tools in your browser it shows that django didnt compile the code for some reason***

you can do the following

first place a css file in the static like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'appname/base.css" %}>
```

than in the css you dont(and you cant) use djangos templates( so what i mean is the {{variables}} and {%  %})
but since your already in static ( the css file is in static)
you can just link it with the default url without using static
so youd just say

url("images/any_image.png")